# Forbidden when accessing image/sticker urls in chat messages returned from Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I received "Forbidden" when accessing an image/sticker link in a chat message return from Microsoft Graph Api.

I received the following chat message from Graph Api (not all properties are not listed):

```
{
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<div><div>Message 499\n<div><span><img src=\"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/82d87df3-b8bd-4bdc-9090-5f8666b32134/channels/19:baf66ad0b75f4656bf20ff5667fae565@thread.skype/messages/1562258187781/hostedContents/aWQ9eF8wLWN1cy1kOC0xYjlkYTQ2NzA1ZTI5YjA5N2QzMDgyZjc2ODZiYTlhMSx0eXBlPTEsdXJsPWh0dHBzOi8vdXMtYXBpLmFzbS5za3lwZS5jb20vdjEvb2JqZWN0cy8wLWN1cy1kOC0xYjlkYTQ2NzA1ZTI5YjA5N2QzMDgyZjc2ODZiYTlhMS92aWV3cy9pbWdv/$value\" width=\"250\" height=\"250\" style=\"vertical-align:bottom; width:250px; height:250px\"></span>\n\n</div>\n\n\n</div>\n</div>"
    }
}
```

Then I tried to access the image link

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/82d87df3-b8bd-4bdc-9090-5f8666b32134/channels/19:baf66ad0b75f4656bf20ff5667fae565@thread.skype/messages/1562258187781/hostedContents/aWQ9eF8wLWN1cy1kOC0xYjlkYTQ2NzA1ZTI5YjA5N2QzMDgyZjc2ODZiYTlhMSx0eXBlPTEsdXJsPWh0dHBzOi8vdXMtYXBpLmFzbS5za3lwZS5jb20vdjEvb2JqZWN0cy8wLWN1cy1kOC0xYjlkYTQ2NzA1ZTI5YjA5N2QzMDgyZjc2ODZiYTlhMS92aWV3cy9pbWdv/$value

Headers:
Authorization: bearer [access_token]
```

The response was:

```
403 Forbidden
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3143682e-4dd2-4057-ad83-e4d7fbf32b98",
            "date": "2019-07-05T07:09:06"
        }
    }
}

Headers:
request-id: 3143682e-4dd2-4057-ad83-e4d7fbf32b98
client-request-id: 3143682e-4dd2-4057-ad83-e4d7fbf32b98
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Southeast Asia","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_2","ADSiteName":"SEA"}}
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2019 07:09:05 GMT
```

However, I was able to list the hosted contents of the same channel:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/82d87df3-b8bd-4bdc-9090-5f8666b32134/channels/19:baf66ad0b75f4656bf20ff5667fae565@thread.skype/messages/1562258187781/hostedContents

Headers:
Authorization: bearer [access_token]

Response
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#teams('82d87df3-b8bd-4bdc-9090-5f8666b32134')/channels('19%3Abaf66ad0b75f4656bf20ff5667fae565%40thread.skype')/messages('1562258187781')/hostedContents",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "aWQ9eF8wLWN1cy1kOC0xYjlkYTQ2NzA1ZTI5YjA5N2QzMDgyZjc2ODZiYTlhMSx0eXBlPTEsdXJsPWh0dHBzOi8vdXMtYXBpLmFzbS5za3lwZS5jb20vdjEvb2JqZWN0cy8wLWN1cy1kOC0xYjlkYTQ2NzA1ZTI5YjA5N2QzMDgyZjc2ODZiYTlhMS92aWV3cy9pbWdv"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I was able to retrieve the image from another chat message in another channel (the general channel) in the same team.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/82d87df3-b8bd-4bdc-9090-5f8666b32134/channels/19:db70de74054944fe9dbce0a592eddb6d@thread.skype/messages/1562252008138/hostedContents/aWQ9eF8wLWN1cy1kNi1iYWY0OTc0ZGNjMjc0MTAwMjI5YmMyZjcyY2Y0ODk2NSx0eXBlPTEsdXJsPWh0dHBzOi8vdXMtYXBpLmFzbS5za3lwZS5jb20vdjEvb2JqZWN0cy8wLWN1cy1kNi1iYWY0OTc0ZGNjMjc0MTAwMjI5YmMyZjcyY2Y0ODk2NS92aWV3cy9pbWdv/$value

Headers:
Authorization: bearer [access_token]
```

The user associated with the access token is one of the owners of the team, but he is not the one posting the chat message containing the image.

What am I missing here?

**Update**: I did more testing and found the following pattern.

- The issue did not happen for General channel.
- For other channels, if a user had not posted any message to a channel, accessing the image link of the chat messages resulted in Forbidden error. After the user posted one message, it could access the link fine.

Looks like a permission synchronization issue. Any idea?

Comment: Is one user trying to read message posted by another user in a channel conversation? Could you please elaborate repro steps?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Sorry for the late reply. Yes it is one user trying to read message posted by another user. I tried to repro it just now but the issue seemed gone. I will monitor the behaviors of my application and will let you know if I encountered the same issue again.

Comment: @Colleen I have the same issue, have you resolved it?

Comment: also wanting to know, if this has been resolved.

Comment: Hi Did you find any answer for this, I am also trying to render an Image but getting 401.